# Problems with Spring Security OAuth2 on JDK 8

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Recently we moved our application written using spring security and the OAuth2 extensions (2.0.4) form jdk 7 to jdk 8.
The over application is built on spring boot 1.2, spring cloud, and spring framework 4.1.4

We started getting OAuth2 failures. The actual error we were getting was:

Failed to process request Error requesting access token.
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:144) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:n
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://ccccc/oauth20/token":Remote host closed connection during handshake; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

When we added this on the command line -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1, it start working.

I note this blog post form Oracle: https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/diagnosing_tls_ssl_and_https

I would rather not have to run our apps with this command line switch.  Any workaround for it? Such as an application setting?

Comment: I guess you can change it in the server if you have control of that? TLSv1 is not the best default for your server, and in any case it should be able to negotiate the protocol. How is the server implemented?

Comment: I am somewhat mystified because all we changed was to compile and run under JDK 8 instead of JDK 7.  More of less, it is a set of spring cloud services running with the spring security  OAUTH2.  It was throwing exceptions until we made that switch.

Comment: So the servers are running on Spring Boot embedded Tomcat? The change to the default TLS version on the client is no mystery (per the link you posted).Why the server can't deal with it is another question.  Is the TLS layer in the apps themselves or in a load balancer? (None of this is related in any way to OAuth2 or Spring Security BTW.)